# Depending on cookie content

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, cookies

can somebody please give me a hint here. I'm new to dealing with web page cookies, in another view (using MVC) I created a cookie with some basic info. Depending on that info I want to change the web page language. The cookie itself is created with JavaScript. I know how to solve this by creating the cookie in the controller, but I don't know which method is the best. Regards.

```
            <script type="text/javascript">
            {
                if (document.cookie.indexOf("Russian") >= 0) {
                    // load partial view here
                    //@{Html.RenderPartial("~/Views/Home/About_.cshtml");}

                }
                else if (document.cookie.indexOf("English") >= 0) {

                    // load partial view here
                    //@{Html.RenderPartial("~/Views/Home/About_Eng.cshtml");}


                }
            }
            </script>
```

Comment: What is your question exactly? What methods are you asking us to compare?

Comment: I'm guessing your not setting a path in in your js cookie. The code where you're actually creating the cookie would be helpful... In terms of whether or not its "best" to create cookies in your views or in your controller, that's a much broader topic of conversation.

Comment: Well, what i wanted was a 'partial view' to be loaded depending on a cookie's content/value. But I'll go with my other method by using the controller instead. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You don't want to do that in JavaScript.  In your controller call Request.Cookies["TheNameOfYourCookie"] then check the collection for the key.  You can set it in on your model or set in to the ViewBag.  Then when rendering your page check the value there and render the section.

Comment: Yes, you are right. I've done this before (from controller) but tried  to do something new here, and failed.